# Can't suppress error message in R Markdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I'm making a tutorial using RMarkdown and I can't suppress the error message I'm getting.  The reason I'm suppressing the error is because the code I'm running requires an API key and I'm intentionally leaving it out.  I just want to display the code, I know it won't work since I'm not using real API key:

````
```{r results='hide', error=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
token <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  #this is your secret token
url <- "myurl.com" #this is your URL
 

result <- postForm(
  uri=url, #pass in url 
  token=token, #pass in token
  content='record',
  format='csv',
  type='flat'
)

```
````

I have `message=FALSE` but the error messages are still showing up when I knit to HTML!  How can I simply display the code above?

Comment: Is there a typo in the fifth line ("uri")? Should it be "url"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
`{r eval = FALSE}`  . This will stop the code from running.

````
Here is the code:

```{r eval = FALSE}
token <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  #this is your secret token
url <- "myurl.com" #this is your URL
 

result <- postForm(
  uri=url, #pass in url 
  token=token, #pass in token
  content='record',
  format='csv',
  type='flat'
)
````

[image]